# serversocket.accept() method blocks even after connection is established

Tags: java, tcp

server

```
    public class Server {

class ServerHelper implements Runnable
    {
        InputStream is;
        private InputStreamReader isr;
        private BufferedReader br;

        public ServerHelper(InputStream is) {
            this.is  = is;
            isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        }



         private void display() throws IOException {

            String s = "";
            System.out.print("client says : ");
            while ( ( s = br.readLine() ) != null ) {                
                System.out.print(s + " ");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                display( );
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        void start( ) throws Exception{
          ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5555);

             while (true) {            
                System.out.println("waiting for conn..");
              Socket accept =   ss.accept();//code hangs over here and doesn't proceed ahead

                 if( accept == null )
                     System.out.println("got null...");
                 System.out.println("got the client req...");
                 ServerHelper sh = new ServerHelper(accept.getInputStream());
                 Thread t = new Thread(sh);
                 t.start();
             }

        }

         public static void main(String[] args) {
             try {
                // TODO code application logic here
                new Server().start();
             } catch (Exception ex) {
                 Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
         }
```

client

```
public class Client {

void start( ) throws Exception{
    System.out.println("enter window size ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int wsize = sc.nextInt();
    Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5555);
    System.out.println("is connected .." + s.isConnected());

    OutputStream outputStream = s.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
    String c  = "y";
    int j = 0;
    do{
        String se = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < wsize; i++) {
            j++;
            se = se + String.valueOf(j);

        }
        pw.println(se);
        pw.flush();

        System.out.println("do u wanna send more....?(y|n)");
        c =  sc.next();
    }while( c.equalsIgnoreCase("y") );

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // TODO code application logic here
        new Client().start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

```
Socket accept =   ss.accept();
```

here my code hangs up i know it is blocking io, but at the client side i did verify that whether client is connected or not but it is showing connected...whats the matter with accept() ? I code in similar manner for all my TCP applications but this is weird ..can any one help

I have also added the ServerHelper code for those who want take a look at that class please..

Comment: That thread has no place else to block and no work to do, so you would expect it to be blocked in `accept` 99.99% of the time.

Comment: There are a number of bad practices in your code.... you are not properly closing the `outputStream` in your Client code... you should send the entire client Socket to the `ServerHelper`, not just the InputStream, etc. Not that this answers your issue though ....

Comment: You should check to see what interface(s) your ServerSocket is bound to, do a `System.out.println(ss.getInetAddress().toString())` before the 'accept' so that you can confirm it is listening on 127.0.0.1 ....

Comment: yes someone here was right ...it prints 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 and not 127.0.0.1 means mine client is connecting to some other process which is listening on 127.0.0.1 and not to my server which is listening on this 0.0.0.0...but what kind of address is this ...can any one explain me this particular concept because as far as my knowledge is concern i know localhost is just 127.0.0.1 ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the call to `accept` is really blocking, then you have another program running that is listening on 5555 and is bound to "127.0.0.1".  Your client is connecting to this other program, so ss.accept still blocks.

**The solution is to find and kill this other process**

Additional information:

Since you did not specify the bind address in your server socket, it is bound to "0.0.0.0" (all interfaces).

It is possible to have one process bind to 127.0.01 and another to bind to 0.0.0.0 (at least on Windows).  I copied some data from tcpview.  The second column is process id.

```
java.exe    5944    TCP 0.0.0.0 5555    0.0.0.0 0   LISTENING                                       
java.exe    5944    TCPV6   [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]   5555    [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]   0   LISTENING                                       
java.exe    5608    TCP 127.0.0.1   5555    0.0.0.0 0   LISTENING
```

I can connect to the process 5944 using `telnet 10.101.16.28 5555` (my local IP address) or connect to process 5608 using `telnet 127.0.0.1 5555`

Comment: Most of what is described here is impossible. You can't have one process listening on 0.0.0.0 and another on 127.0.0.1, and you can't have a process listening on 'everything except 127.0.0.1', all on the same TCP port. It is impossible. The suggested change won't fix this. For a start, there is no problem to fix. -1

Comment: @EJP - I agree my answer was unclear.  I have removed the proposed code change since it was an aid to understanding the problem and was never intended to be a fix.  However I stand by my statement about two processes listening on the same port if the bind address is different, and have added some data to support this.

Comment: yes guido u was right ....thanks ...my server was listening at 0.0.0.0 and not on 127.0.0.1..but i didnt understand why so ? is this because some other process was already running on 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on your code:

```
while (true) {            
      System.out.println("waiting for conn..");
      Socket accept =   ss.accept();
      .................
}
```

You call `ss.accept()` into infinite loop. Once your client is connected `accept()` returns the `Socket` instance. Then you pass this socket to server helper running in its own thread and return to `ss.accept()`, so your server is ready to accept other clients. Your code looks OK. Unfortunately you have not sent code of your `ServerHelper` and did not explain whether your client successfully sends data to server, however so far everything looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it blocks. It is waiting for a connection. That's what it's supposed to do. BTW checking the result of accept() for null is pointless. It won't be null. Possibly this is your misconception: are you expecting it to return null if there is no incoming connection? It doesn't do that. See the Javadoc.